# Joomla , Joomfish language translation for whole page not only content!

Tags: php, joomla, joomfish

When i click the flag to change the language , the content of the page is changing but not the other modules listed in the page. Example If i'm in my profile page then everything should be in that language! How i can make like that???

Comment: You must get language file of all modules which are being displayed. If you can;t get it, then you need to create your self.

Comment: I checked most of the modules not providing that!! So could you suggest me any tutorials or documentation to do myself or plz explain me how to do!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your JOOMLA INSTALL/language/en-GB folder. You will see a bunch of language files for every component, module, plugin, and template that uses a language file. You will need to make a corresponding file for each language you support on your website.

Answer (score 1):

[Language INI maker](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/6347) extension might be helpful in your quest. It will scan a given component for all translatable text and create an ini file for you to edit. Be careful, as it is a bit buggy (for example, if I remember correctly, it only recognizes the translatable text if it is enclosed in single quotes...). Having said that, it should at least make a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it's working only for the components how i can make for modules??

Comment: I guess you will need to look at the code of the module and find all translatable text yourself.